# How to get words like *ologist and *ology to stem/lemmatize to the same root?

Tags: python, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I've been playing with a bunch of stemmers and lemmatizers in [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), but none do what I want. I have a bunch of words like "radiologist", "radiology", "cardiologist", "cardiology", etc... where I'd like to have *ologist go to the same bucket as *ology. I've tried PorterStemmer, SnowballStemmer, and WordNet's Lemmatizer in Python, but nothing sends these to the same bucket. It's seems like stemming should accomplish this, and these aren't incredibly uncommon words. How would you go about achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Morfessor? It features a bunch of morph segmenting algorithms. Apparently, the kind of analysis that you are looking for is possible using this tool. Here is the link [1]: http://asr.aalto.fi/morfessordemo/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> s = 'cardiology'
>>> s = s[:-5] if s.endswith('ology') else s
>>> s = s[:-7] if s.endswith('ologist') else s
>>> s
'cardi'
>>> s = 'cardiologist'
>>> s = s[:-5] if s.endswith('ology') else s
>>> s = s[:-7] if s.endswith('ologist') else s
>>> s
'cardi'
```

Comment: C'mon, you know that's not what I mean.

Comment: It really depends on how your data looks like to find the best fit / best way to "hack" the existing lemmatizers/stemmers. Sharing a representative sample of your data would help improve the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

The process of stemming/lemmatization assumes removing of inflectional suffixes only (i. e. remove `-s` suffix from the word `radiologists`), while you want to remove the derivational suffixes as well.

Try [Lingua Robot](https://www.linguarobot.io). It's capable of segmenting the words into morphemes. For example, the word `simplifications` is segmented into the base word `simple` (I assume this is what you want to retrieve) and derivational suffixes (`-ify`, `-ation` and `-s`). Your case is not that simple as according to the API `radiologist` consists of affixes only (`radio-` + `-logy` + `-ist`). Somehow, you will need to figure what affix to leave in such cases. I'm also not sure if you want to leave prefixes or not (`preprocess` → `process`). Besides it, you will need to take into account compound words as they contain several roots.